# Does amplitude of electric field and magnetic field vary with distance in em waves?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Does the amplitude of electric field and magnetic field of an em wave vary with distance?

Comment: Distance from what?

Comment: Distance from whatever :-), it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a spherically symmetric em wave created by a point source then the intensity of the wave (namely the power transferred through unit area) drops according to the inverse square law (this follows because the total power radiated over a sphere of fixed radius remains the same, so as you increase the size of the sphere the power per unit area drops). For an em wave the (time averaged) intensity depends upon the square of the amplitude, so the amplitude of the wave will decrease with distance.

If you are talking about a plane wave, then the amplitude is constant.